# trying to create my bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a simple bash script.
(just started working on bash scripting)
the script is simple. There is an issue with rsyslog service and from time to time dies.
I am trying to make a script to check if service is dead to restart it 
till now I want to check if my conditions are ok  but it seems I am getting an error. Can you advice me ?

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
a="dead"
b="running"
while i in $(/etc/init.d/rsyslog status | grep -o 'running\|dead');
do
if
[ "$a" == "$i" ];
then
echo "service rsyslog is dead "
if
[ "$b" == "$i" ];
then
echo "service rsyslog is running"
else
echo "nothing to do";
fi;
done
-------------
```

I am getting the following syntax error.

./rsyslogcheck.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./rsyslogcheck.sh: line 17:`done'

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Run this through https://www.shellcheck.net - the first `if` is missing its `fi`.

Comment: You don't need to use both a semicolon (`;`) *and* a newline to separate statements / commands.

Comment: You are also confusing `while` loops with `for` loops. There is no `in` operator in `bash`; `in` is just a keyword used to "spell" `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here:

- Invalid `while` loop syntax
- Unnecessary loop: it seems you don't need a loop at all
- Missing closing `fi` of an `if` that was opened

I suppose you're looking for something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
status=$(/etc/init.d/rsyslog status | grep -o 'running\|dead')
case "$status" in
dead) echo "service rsyslog is dead";;
running) echo "service rsyslog is running";;
*) echo "nothing to do";;
esac
```